# How to count most repeated value in MySQL subquery without using Limit function

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

I want to count the most repeated values in a table but its being done in a sub query and my SQLyog doesn't support that type of query, below is my query:

```
SELECT `band`.`band_id`,`member_id`,`member_name`,`contact_no`  
FROM seasons 
INNER JOIN programs_recorded ON  programs_recorded.season_id=seasons.season_id 
INNER JOIN programs ON programs_recorded.program_id=programs.program_id 
INNER JOIN songs_performed ON songs_performed.program_id=programs.program_id 
INNER JOIN songs ON songs.song_id=songs_performed.song_id 
INNER JOIN `band` ON `band`.`song_id`=`songs`.`song_id` 
INNER JOIN `band_member` ON `band_member`.`band_id`=`band`.`band_id` 
WHERE `band`.`song_id` = ANY ( SELECT `songs_performed`.`song_id` 
                               FROM `songs_performed` 
                               GROUP BY `song_id` 
                               HAVING COUNT(`s_id`)>3)
GROUP BY `member_id` ;
```

As you can see above I have written `COUNT(s_id)>3` which is not generic, one solution is that I use GROUP BY function along with order by and limit but SQLyog gives error saying it not supported in this version.

Comment: What's wrong with LIMIT? I don't get it

Comment: It gives error saying Limit function is not supported in all/any/some sub queries. etc

Comment: But there is no LIMIT in the query !?!?!?!

Comment: There's No limit because that query didn't work I posted here the one which runs but is not generic. I mean It WORKS because of that count(s_id)>3

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, what's wrong with something like this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.band_id
              , member_id
              , member_name
              , contact_no  
           FROM seasons ss
           JOIN programs_recorded pr
             ON pr.season_id = ss.season_id 
           JOIN programs p
             ON pr.program_id = p.program_id 
           JOIN songs_performed sp
             ON sp.program_id = p.program_id 
           JOIN songs s
             ON s.song_id = sp.song_id 
           JOIN band b
             ON b.song_id = s.song_id 
           JOIN band_member bm
             ON bm.band_id = b.band_id 
           JOIN 
              ( SELECT sp.song_id 
                  FROM songs_performed sp
                 GROUP 
                    BY song_id 
                HAVING COUNT(s_id) > 3
              ) x
             ON x.song_id = b.song_id;
```

??

Comment: Well. I submitted my project yesterday.. The problem was that.. as You are also using count (s_id) >3 . This >3 is not generic because I know that this is the most repeated value  in my database. If instead of 3 I wrote 1 then it would print all the data which occurs more then once in the database not the one which occurs the most . anyways thanks for your contribution.